# Why won't a:active work in sidebar widget?

Tags: css

I have the following in my css:

```
.categories-widget li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.categories-widget li a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and this in my sidebar.php:

```
<h2 class="big">Categories</h2>
<ul class="categories-widget">
   <?php
   global $parent_id;
   wp_list_categories('show_count=1&title_li=&child_of='.$gateway_parent_id.'&show_count=0&hide_empty=0'); ?>
</ul>
```

The a:hover works, but not the a:active. Is there a reason for this? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please, put the *processed* HTML code.

Comment: what you mean it wont work? so when you press the `a`  nothing happens?

Comment: It probably works, they simply have the exact same css (text-decroration:underline), try to defer one of them in some way from the other

Comment: It links, but there's no indication that someone is on a particular category's page. I've tried other decoration, such as bold with no results. 

Processed HTML:

`<ul class="categories-widget">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-13 current-cat">
<a title="View all posts filed under Issues" href="http://www.ggaissues/">Issues</a>
</li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wont work since you have:

```
.categories-widget li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.categories-widget li a:active {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and the **:active** pseudo selector will match when an element is currently being pressed down on by the mouse cursor. [so it is doing the same thing..](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/)

try :

.categories-widget li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

```
.categories-widget li a:active {
position:fixed;
padding-top:1px;
color:red;
}
```